# Detecting Web vs Windows application

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

We have a library that is shared in .net between both Web and Windows (forms and console) applications.   When used as a Web application, a couple of variables need to be read from cookies.   Otherwise it needs to read the same variables from the Windows registry.   I cannot seem to work out a good solution to doing this such that the same library compiles for all environments.  Specifically, the web libraries for reading cookies would not be included in the Windows apps (and thus break the compile), let alone detecting one environment vs another.  Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: What is wrong with a config setting?

Comment: To me this sounds like you'll probably need some kind of abstraction layer for these kind of variables, since the actual implementation is different for different platforms (stored in registry vs. stored in cookies). Have you considered creating some kind of "variable-container" interface or something similar? (That way each application may implement its own mechanism for reading/writing these variables)

Comment: @Mathew, I cannot do it in the config since the general user does not have write access to it.

Comment: @bassfader I have considered this exact possibility, however, I am not the only developer so I have to work within the constraints of the scope of the application and that would break it.   I can read/write to cookies and to registry.   Beyond that requires meetings, and red-tape.

Answer (score 3):

If you host in IIS you can read Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables("APP_POOL_ID") and then act accordingly if the variable exists

Comment: @Vladmir does this return true if the application is running as a Windows application on a machine that is also a web server?  Also I think you meant the singulular, not plural "Variable".

Comment: It returns not "true" but value of environment variable inside the process. so if application is windows application the variable won't exist. and yes, it is probably singular. I don't remember by heart, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Depending on architecture of your library, this information should be provided by the client code. I.e you provide some abstraction layer that will be up to client code to fill in.

I'll show a simple example of what I mean. In your library you have an interface like this:

```
public interface ISettingsProvider
{
    public string GetSettingA();
    public string GetSettingB();
}
```

And then your library code that needs access to settings will have to take a dependency on `ISettingsProvider`:

```
public class MyLibraryClient
{
    private readonly ISettingsProvider settingsProvider;
    public MyLibraryClient(ISettingsProvider settingsProvider)
    {
         this.settingsProvider = settingsProvider;
    }

    public void MyAwesomeMethod()
    {
        var settingA = settingsProvider.GetSettingA();
        // do more stuff with your settings
    }
}
```

Then your client code should implement `ISettingsProvider`:

```
public class WebSettingsProvider : ISettingsProvider
{
    public string GetSettingA()
    {
         // go get the value from cookies
         return Cookies["MyCookie1"];
    }
    public string GetSettingB()
    {
         // go get the value from cookies
         return Cookies["MyCookie2"];
    }
}
```

And very similar thing goes for settings stored in registry.

And when client code is accessing your library, they will have to instantite an instance of settings provider and give it to you.

This way your library does not know anything about web or Windows. You got to keep your code cleaner and it is all a lot more testable. And you don't have to take dependencies on `System.Web` and ultimately push that depdency on client code that does not work with web, i.e. Windows applications.

I know you have said you are limited in the amount of changes you can do. My answer to this is: you can't make an omlet without breaking eggs. This will be the most clean way to do what you want, everything else will have drawbacks.

Comment: It's scrambling the eggs and getting whipped by the cooks I am concerned most about.   I was working on a very similar solution to the above.  But yours is a bit more efficient.  I'll test away...

Comment: @JonGlazer You should be concerned about the taste of the omlet! Because omlet with egg shell in it tastes rather nasty! I know, I've done the same thing (web vs non-web, not the omlet) a few times and practice indicate that this is by far the best way

Answer (score -1):

In a Web-Environment you should have `HttpContext.Current`. If you are calling the same from the Console (or a WinForms-Application) this should be null instead of the Context.

To access this you need a reference to `Sytem.Web`. There should be no issue when you add this reference and access your backend from the Winforms-Application.

Example:

```
public bool ImInDaWeb() {
  return System.Web.HttpContext.Current!=null;
}
```

Even in a web-application, HttpContext.Current *can* be null, but as you are needing this detection for reading/writing cookies you will have to detect this within a valid request already (and not on Application start for example).

Comment: a) checking for `HttpContext.Current` like this can throw exceptions even if it is a web application. b) if this is a web application, but currently there is no http request (like at application startup), you will get null for current context, so this will give you incorrect answer. c) also you are adding a dependency on `System.Web` which is not always a good thing, especially if you are working with netstandard

Comment: It does look like a step in the right direction though.  Any other ideas for detecting this?

Comment: @trailmax I added something to explain (b). For (a) IMHO this is similar. He will already have some System.Web-Reference if he wants to read/write cookie data

Comment: Yet `HttpContext.Current` can throw exception in some situations, even if it is not null - not 100% reliable, so at least you need to wrap with  `try-catch`. Yet if app is starting and you are trying to decide if this is web or not, you will get a wrong answer and will try access registry instead.

Comment: try..catch is something I usually don't write in SO-answers but expect the poster to care for  :) 
Nonetheless: I agree with you on the "non-100%-reliable" topic